# CMake and Boost error on Centos 7- Could not find the following Boost libraries

Tags: boost, cmake

I am running on the Centos 7 and try to install the dropEst to the pc.
[https://github.com/hms-dbmi/dropEst][1]

my configuration is 
CentOS Linux 7
boost_1_69_0
cmake-3.14.0-rc1

I get the following error when I running the CMake and Boost.

Could not find the following Boost libraries:

boost_filesystem
boost_system
boost_thread
boost_unit_test_framework

Here is the output of the command.

```
(base) [ly@localhost boost_1_69_0]$ ./b2 cxxflags="-std=c++11"
include="$LOCAL_LIBS/include/" search="$LOCAL_LIBS/lib/" link=static
threading=multi install --prefix=$LOCAL_LIBS
```

> Performing configuration checks
>
> ```
> - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached)
> - default architecture     : x86 (cached)
> - zlib                     : yes (cached)
> - bzip2                    : yes (cached)
> - lzma                     : yes (cached)
> - zstd                     : no  (cached)
> - native-atomic-int32-supported : yes (cached)
> - native-syslog-supported  : yes (cached)
> - pthread-supports-robust-mutexes : yes (cached)
> - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes (cached)
> - compiler-supports-avx2   : yes (cached)
> - has_icu builds           : yes (cached)
> - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes (cached)
> - BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= 4.3.0 : no  (cached)
> ```
>
> Component configuration:
>
> ```
> - atomic                   : not building
> - chrono                   : not building
> - container                : not building
> - context                  : not building
> - contract                 : not building
> - coroutine                : not building
> - date_time                : not building
> - exception                : not building
> - fiber                    : not building
> - filesystem               : building
> - graph                    : not building
> - graph_parallel           : not building
> - iostreams                : building
> - locale                   : not building
> - log                      : building
> - math                     : not building
> - mpi                      : not building
> - program_options          : not building
> - python                   : not building
> - random                   : not building
> - regex                    : not building
> - serialization            : not building
> - stacktrace               : not building
> - system                   : building
> - test                     : building
> - thread                   : building
> - timer                    : not building
> - type_erasure             : not building
> - wave                     : not building
> ```
>
> ...patience... ...patience... ...patience... ...patience... ...found
>   32829 targets... ...updating 42 targets... common.copy
>   /home/ly/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.a gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/codecvt_error_category.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/path.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/path_traits.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/portability.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/unique_path.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/utf8_codecvt_facet.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/windows_file_codecvt.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/error_code.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/lockpool.o gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/gregorian/greg_month.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/gregorian/date_generators.o gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/c_regex_traits.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/cpp_regex_traits.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/cregex.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/fileiter.o gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/icu.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/instances.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/posix_api.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/regex.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/regex_debug.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/regex_raw_buffer.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/regex_traits_defaults.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/static_mutex.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/w32_regex_traits.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/wc_regex_traits.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/wide_posix_api.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/winstances.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/usinstances.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/pthread/thread.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/pthread/once.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/future.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/chrono.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/thread_clock.o
>   gcc.compile.c++
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/process_cpu_clocks.o
>   gcc.archive
>   bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_log.a
>   common.copy /home/ly/local/lib/libboost_log.a ...updated 42 targets...

```
(base) [ly@localhost ~]$ cd dropEst/build
(base) [ly@localhost build]$ cmake .. && make
```

> CMake Error at
>   /home/ly/local/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2124
>   (message):   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.69.0
>
> Boost include path: /home/ly/boost_1_69_0
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_filesystem
>       boost_system
>       boost_thread
>       boost_unit_test_framework
> ```
>
> Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You
>   may   need to install these additional Boost libraries. 
>   Alternatively, set   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing
>   Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT   to the location of Boost. Call Stack
>   (most recent call first):   CMake/deps.cmake:19 (find_package)
>   CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at CMake/deps.cmake:34 (find_package):   Policy
>   CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses _ROOT variables.
>   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the
>   cmake_policy   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
>
> CMake variable R_ROOT is set to:
>
> ```
> /usr/lib64/R
> ```
>
> For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable. Call Stack (most
>   recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:18 (include) This warning is for
>   project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Found R: /usr/lib64/R
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/ly/dropEst/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
>   "/home/ly/dropEst/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".